# Android Post values from Recyclerview Checkbox to database

Tags: java, android, mysql, checkbox

I'm working on an employee attendance attendance applicaion, for that I'm listing employee namelist from my MySQL database to android RecyclerView. Everything is working fine. But  what I actually wanted is, I want to update my attendance table with the CheckBox values, my table contains 3 columns **id,emp_id,emp_attn**, If the checkbox is checked for an employee, the app should post it as checked ! So how can i identify each checkbox in my recyclerview,

**MyAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Akshay N Shaju on 10/20/2017.
 */

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<Listitems> listitemses;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<Listitems> listitemses, Context context) {
        this.listitemses = listitemses;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Listitems listitem = listitemses.get(position);
        holder.CbHead.setText(listitem.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(listitem.getDesc());

        holder.CbHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,listitem.getHead(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
 }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listitemses.size();
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CheckBox CbHead;
        public TextView textViewDesc;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            CbHead = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CbHead);
            textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDisc);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.LinearLyout1);
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String URL_DATA = "https://xxxxxxx.com/sample.json";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private List<Listitems> listitemses;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        listitemses = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();
        }
        private void loadRecyclerViewData(){
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data");
            progressDialog.show();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    URL_DATA,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("employee");
                                for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Listitems item = new Listitems(
                                    o.getString("name"),
                                    o.getString("id"),
                                    o.getString("image")
                                            );
                                    listitemses.add(item);
                                }
                                adapter =  new MyAdapter(listitemses,getApplicationContext());
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    }
```

**ListItems.java**

```
/**
 * Created by Akshay N Shaju on 10/20/2017.
 */

public class Listitems {
    private String head;
    private String desc;
    private String imageurl;

    public Listitems(String head, String desc, String imageurl) {
        this.head = head;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }

    public String getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public String getImageurl() {
        return imageurl;
    }
}
```

Here in my adapter I tried an onClick Listner, which toast the employee name when checked and it worked ! but how can I get all the checkbox status and post it to my database table when save button clicked.

Comment: Instead of onClickListener you have to use on check changed listener.

Comment: @Xenolion So how can i identify checkbox for each employees on http post ?

Comment: I am writting some code for you just gimme some time.Wait a little @Akshay

Comment: @Xenolion Okay ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the state in your ListItem, whenever the state of the CheckBox changes:

```
public class Listitems {
   ...
   public bool isChecked;
   ...
}
```

Instead of `onClick`, listen to the state change instead:

```
holder.CbHead.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        listitem.isChecked = isChecked
    }
});
```

Finally when binding, make sure to reflect the checked state of the CheckBox:

```
holder.CbHead.setText(listitem.getHead());
holder.CbHead.setChecked(listitem.isChecked)
```

You are using a recycler view so while the CheckBox is still on screen it will hold your "checked" state. However once it scrolls off screen, it will be recycled. Hence you need to store the state somewhere, your own ListItem is the best bet

Comment: @Hai I'm new to android ! Can you guide me to do the same ?

Comment: Show me your Listitems then

Comment: @Hai Ok, but i may have n number of employees in the list , so how can i identify each of them and their Checkbox value !

Comment: What do you mean? List<Listitems> listitemses contains your data, including the checkbox value. You can either send that back to your PHP server the same way you read from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157194/discussion-between-akshay-n-shaju-and-hai).